# My web app encounters different caching behaviour in chrome and safari - chrome gets 304 on refresh but safari keeps getting 200

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I pick a random asset to illustrate the problem: http://www.smh.com.au/content/dam/images/g/q/t/u/p/3/image.related.square.80x75.gquf3q.10rhp3.png/1471481192415.jpg

In chrome, when I first load the jpg file, I get `200` response as expected.

[image]

Subsequent refresh will get 304. Again as expected.

[image]

Now if I do the same in safari, it is the first fetch:

[image]

And here is after reload

[image]

Both try to hit the server and reload.

Why the discrepancy of caching behavior? How can I ensure I can get 304 in safari when reload?

Comment: That's indeed a strange behavior, It's like Safari needs a referrer to use the cached media... Try [from this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4uuf2ec5/), then the cached image is used... Also strange that you get it in your page since I guess you're accessing the files from somewhere.